# can't download gcc 11.3.0

Tags: nvidia, gcc, cuda

I have gcc 11.4.0 in my Ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine with kernel 5.19.0-32-generic. I want to install NVIDIA CUDA. But in the official supported versions table, it says that: [cuda ubuntu supported versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHcdo.png). So I tried to remove gcc 11.4.0 from my sistem and install 11.3.0. I downloaded the zip folder of it, then changed directory into 11.3.0 folder. Then I runned ./configure but it gave me that error: "configure: error: *** A compiler with support for C++11 language features is required." What should I do now? I can not install CUDA with gcc 11.4.0 and it says gcc 11.3.0 is the right version but when I try installing 11.3.0 it gives me error.

Comment: Please check you've applied all security fixes on your system, as Ubuntu 22.04 LTS using the HWE kernel now uses 6.2 from 23.04, or if using GA kernel that it still 5.15. The 5.19 kernel was from 22.10 and applied to Ubuntu 22.04.2, so your details show you behind on applying security fixes.  You can refer to https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/08/11/ubuntu-22-04-3-lts-released/ for the ISO release of 22.04.3, but installed systems upgraded in the week before that (*weekend before getting the last of the upgrades of 22.04.3*).

Comment: @guiverc thanks for your suggestion about security fixes. I upgraded my sistem and now I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS and kernel 6.2.0-26-generic. But in the supported platforms list [link](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html) I can not find the platform has my platforms properties. So does it mean that I can not use NVIDIA CUDA with my sistem? Regards.